# how to upload records in automate UI testing

Tags: ios, swift, ui-testing

My app collects location information from the user. How can I upload a lot of location records in the backend and meanwhile automatically test if the front end is accessible? I don't want to test it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Store location data locally in phone use either **core data** or **sqlite** and then upload data in small chunks to backend and for UI testing use some automated tools like **MonkeyTalk**.

Comment: Maybe it is a good start point. But I need more details. How can I get access to data in UI Testing class?